# Rails 3 - how to send_file in response of a remote form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sendfile

I have this coupon form

```
    <%form_for(:download,:download,:url=>{:controller=>"coupons",:action=>"verifycoupon"},:remote=>true) do |f| %>
    <%=text_field :download,:code%>
    <%=f.submit "verify"%>
    <%end%>
```

and after validating the code on the controller's action i have a confirmation like:

```
render :update do |page|
    page.alert "OK"
end
```

Now I want to send a file to the browser with the `send_file` instruction but nothing seems to happen

```
send_file("/path/to/my/file.extension")
```

and in the log I can see

```
"Sent file /path/to/my/file.extension (0.1ms)"
```

I was wondering if there's something like

```
render :update do |page|
   page.send_file("/path/to/my/file.extension")
end
```

```
#### Update #######
```

my Controller's action looks something like

```
def verifycoupon
   code = Code.find(params[:download][:code])
   if code
     if code.is_active?
     render :update do |page|
        page.alert "ok"
     end
       send_file("/path/to/my/file.extension")
     else
       render :update do |page|
          page.alert "this code has already been used"
       end
     end
   else
   render :update do |page|
     page.alert "Code does't exist"
   end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'll leave it there, its just something basic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard that the solution is to send a redirect to an end-point where does the send_file back from Ajax.

So,  Ajax Request  -> Server -> Response -> Redirect -> Client -> request which downloads -> you stay on the same page.

```
def show
  # if javascript, then redirect to file_sender
end

def file_sender
  # Send file from here.
end
```

See here http://anaphoral.blogspot.com/2009/03/sendfile-or-senddata-in-linktoremote.html

Comment: Now, how can i protect the `file_sender` action? like under the protected statemen, because if I put the `file_sender` action under the `protected` statement i can't do the `page.redirect_to :action=>"file_sender"`

Comment: Why dont you make it a public facing endpoint but provide the same before_filter authentication/protection you provide to the "show" action?

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem, well kind of.

In my **view** I had a `link_to` tag with `remote: true`.

The link aimed an action that produced a PDF. The PDF was generated (with prawn and thinreports) and sent, but the download dialog did not popup.

So I remove the `remote: true` and add a `target: '_self'`, so it ended up like this (I am using haml)

```
!= link_to image_tag( 'print.png' ) + (I18n.t :buttons)[:comments][:print],
    customer_comment_path(@address_book),
    { target: '_self' }
```

And it worked just fine.

I did not have to do the "*Ajax Request -> Server -> Response -> Redirect -> Client -> request which downloads -> ...*" mentioned above.

Comment: Ups!, I forgot, the `sendfile` command is in my **CustomerComentsController** under the **show** method.

Answer (score 1):

Where to you call `sendfile`? I have a controller action like this:

```
def show
  # ... skipped initalization of requestedfile
  if File.exists?(requestedfile)
    send_file(requestedfile, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "inline"
  end
end
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to use `send_file` in a `remote` function called from a remote `form_for`

Comment: Well, maybe it would be good to update the question to be more clear on this.

Comment: There's the update but i think i found the right answer on Aditya Sanghi's answer